# What is the equivalent of "Referential Integrity for CCK" in drupal 7?

Tags: 7

Is there a Drupal 7 equivalent for the [Referential Integrity for CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck_referential_integrity) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [sandbox project](http://drupal.org/sandbox/claudiucristea/1263038) for a D7 port that performs cleanup on cron.

Otherwise drupal supports databases that do not enforce referential integrity, so it has not (to my knowledge) been a core issue.

Comment: hey can i ask another question here too? @triskelion what is cron btw? that experimental project says "Unlike Referential Integrity for CCK, this version is performing the data cleanup at cron run " so can you enlighten me what is cron?

Comment: In the *nix world, maintenance tasks are performed on a schedule by the servers. The daemon is called cron. Drupal also performs site maintenance tasks by a schedule, and those tasks are enabled in modules by a hook_cron function. In other words, the database cleanup would not happen immediately, but on the next scheduled maintenance run.

Comment: ok i get you.. last question swear. what is *nix and what is daemon?

Comment: Unix, linux and other unix clones. And a deamon is a program that runs in the background to provide a service.

Comment: ok thanks. but isnt there a stable module in drupal 7 that do node reference clean ups?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.